# How can a non-recursive function appear twice in a stack trace?

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, system-calls, stack-trace, virtual-memory

I have a function `check` that is roughly like this:

```
void check() {
    // ...
    
    // Make some execute-only memory readable for subsequent inspection
    // using the mprotect system call
    mprotect(addr, length, PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC); // #1
    
    // Read the memory and do some integrity checks ...
    if (addr[42] == 13) { // #2
        // ...
    }
}
```

My program sometimes crashes with a segmentation fault in the line marked with #2, where the memory is read.

When I look at the stack trace, there are two(!) entries of my function `check`:

1. Function `check`, line #2 (where the memory is read)
2. Function `check`, line #1 (the `mprotect` system call)

So according to the stack trace, my function is somehow called from within itself, and that call happens in line #1 where I do the `mprotect` system call.

How is this possible?

**EDIT: As requested, here's the original stack trace:**

```
Crashed: Thread :  SIGSEGV  0x000000752eaba9a8
#00 pc 0xddc08 libnative-49.so (isAnyFunctionBeingHooked(_JNIEnv*, unsigned char const**, unsigned long) [NativeLib.cpp:185])
#01 pc 0xddc00 libnative-49.so (isAnyFunctionBeingHooked(_JNIEnv*, unsigned char const**, unsigned long) [NativeLib.cpp:164])
#02 pc 0xd7b54 libnative-49.so (dFAH(_JNIEnv*) [NativeLib.cpp:267])
// Following entries are outside of my code ...
```

Line 164 is the call to `mprotect`.
Line 185 is reading the memory previously made readable by `mprotect`.

Comment: Can you include the call stack in your question (please edit the question)?

Comment: @Dominique: What I wrote in the question basically is the stack trace, stripped down to the essential information. Of course my function has a different name and the line numbers are different, but my function does appear twice and the lines are those where the memory is read and where the `mprotect` call happens.

Comment: Basically a stack trace explained with english words is not a stack trace.  Think that you are talking with developers that know that many times, a stack trace interpreted by a human becomes blurred by a bad interpretation.  Please, you are asking for help and you have been requested to include the stack trace as it was produced by the debugger, not your interpretation, that may be erroneous.  Think also that the stack trace can be also have been corrupted if you have accessed memory that is not well pointed to.  So, please edit your question and post the real stack trace in the debugger formt

Comment: @LuisColorado Stack trace added as per your request.

Comment: The stack traces make reference to lines 164 and 185 (which differ in 21 lines of code, and that's not the positions in the code you show, which differ in 3 lines of code)  Could you show a [Minimal, complete and reproducible example of code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please?

Comment: I'm now getting this same situation with a destructor which uses the `delete` operator on 4 of it's members. The lines in the stack trace are the first and last `delete` statement... wild